# Devise force logout if logged out from facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, devise

I have the following scenario:

1. User logs in with Facebook connect (devise, omniauth)
2. User starts browsing around the site
3. User logs out from Facebook
4. User can still browse around. <-- how can I prevent this from happening?

I basically want to redirect the user to the login page if he is logged out from Facebook

I'm using Rails 3.1 with devise, omniauth.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a misconception here. Once the user has granted your app privileges to access the Facebook profile--either by virtue of being logged into Facebook in another browser tab, or by explicitly logging into Facebook when redirected--then the OAuth handshake it done and your user is authenticated. The authentication state is now kept locally with your app; you presumably have a session cookie with the `user_id`, which Devise will handle for you.

The Facebook login on the browser is only necessary to **log in**, not to authenticate each single request.

You could presumably run the OAuth handshake on every single request, but that would be a lot of performance overhead, and also Facebook may rate limit you.

What is the business case for this scenario? Why do you think you want this?